# Which formats are available for Keys Enum?

Tags: .net, string, format, key

I have a next problem. I need to represent a pressed keys combination in a text form. I got pressed keys from **KeyEventArgs e**...
And when I try to use following code
**e.KeyData.ToString();** I got something like this: **N, Control** .... But I want to get **Ctrl+N** string.
I think that must be present specific format for **String.Format** because when i bind property with type **Keys** to the **DataGridView** I saw in the table cell string **Ctrl+N**. It's mean that DataGridView can do this, and i think this is not done manually...

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Keys** values are probably displayed using the **TypeConverter** belonging it.

If you want to emulate the behavior of the **DataGridView**, you should use

```
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Keys));
string displayName = converter.ConvertToString(e.KeyData);
```

The **Keys** type is tagged with `[TypeConverter(typeof(KeysConverter))]`, which is what `GetConverter` should return.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e.aspx), there is nothing built-in to do this. I suspect the grid is just substituing ", " for "+".